# How do I find the end of speaker wire in a finished wall?

Tags: wiring, cabling, home-theater

I purchased a home with a media room that was prewired for surround sound. One end of the wires is in a low voltage single gang box, the other ends terminate somewhere in the corners of the room. There are some telltale plaster spots that have been painted over, but I would like to confirm the wire location before punching into the drywall.

What do you recommend for locating the wires? Infrared? Tone generator? Something else?

Comment: Why not just rewire so the speakers can be placed wherever you wish? Might be easier than dealing with a dubious installation.

Comment: @keshlam - Why didn't you answer instead of commenting? Your answer refers to the tool I mentioned, a Tone generator, and was the tool I used for the job. In this case it was very easy because I only had to verify the patched wallboard was where the wire was located.

Comment: @benrudgers, I am not made of money. Removing the drywall to run the speaker wires to opposite ends of the room is not an option.

Comment: With a fishtape and a drill and a flex bit, it's often practical to run wire in existing construction. It may wind up being the best option anyway if what is in the wall doesn't meet your expectations. But it's only a suggestion. That's why I put it as a comment not an answer.

Comment: @benrudgers thank you for commenting. I have not used a flex bit before, but it sounds useful. I'm not worried about the qualify of the wire, just where it terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the way I'd find it would be to get a wire tracer. These consist of a transmitter that hooks to one end of the wire to use it as an antenna, and a short-range (and sometimes directional) receiver which you can then use to find the wire emitting that signal. That will let you trace a wire through the wall's surface. (There are several variants of this, at different price points; the more expensive ones can even be used on live AC circuits.)

[Originally a comment, since I thought it was a bit short/shallow as an answer.]

Comment: Not all answers need to be "War and Peace"; sometimes short and to the point is a better answer (or in this case, plenty, given a current lack of competition.)

Comment: This was exactly the tool I used for the job. I had a cheap version (~$60), but it does the job of proving the nasty patches were hiding my cable ends.